# The specified deps.json [path\App.Web.Site\App.Web.deps.json] does not exist

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019

I try to run entity framework (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.24) migration on my .net core web application and I am getting this:

```
PM> add-migration "initial"
The specified deps.json [path\App.Web.Site\App.Web.deps.json] does not exist
```

What is the problem here?

P.S. App.Web.deps.json can be found in path\App.Web.Site\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2 instead

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the problem is, but downgrading visual studio 2019 to 2017 somehow solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem after I updated Visual Studio to 16.1.3. Create new project, run it, stop debug, then I read the following in Package Manager Console:

```
PM> add-migration -v initial
Using project 'TestEf2'.
Using startup project 'TestEf2'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile G:\testef\TestEf2\TestEf2.deps.json --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\snytko\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.2.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll" migrations add initial --json --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly G:\testef\TestEf2\TestEf2.dll --startup-assembly G:\testef\TestEf2\TestEf2.dll --project-dir G:\testef\TestEf2\ --language C# --working-dir G:\testef\TestEf2 --root-namespace TestEf2
The specified deps.json [G:\testef\TestEf2\TestEf2.deps.json] does not exist
PM>
```

I filed this to microsoft using their feedback system. Hope it works. Generated file is at another path:

```
G:\testef\TestEf2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\TestEf2.deps.json
```

One can just copy all contents of the bin directory to the path where EF searches the deps file everytime it's needed to work with migrations..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VS 16.11.7 and it gave me headaches.

Of course there are some workarounds here:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16386

These steps also worked for me:

a) dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-ef (To Remove it only if it exists)

b) dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef (To Install it if it does not exist)

c) dotnet ef (To see that it is installed correctly)

d) dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

e) dotnet ef database update

The most easy way to find out if you have the same problem as me is to run this command from the VS Package Manager console:

```html
(Get-Project).ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties.Item('OutputPath').Value
```

and initially the result was a null exception.
On another machine, the result was "bin\Debug\net5.0"

**BUT I finally SOLVE the issue by un-installing and reinstalling the following components** from Visual Studio Installer:

- ASP.NET and web development
- Azure development
- .net cross-platform development

Hope it helps!
Thumbs up!

Answer (score -1):

try adding this to your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```